# ORA:00900 - Invalid SQL Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to the vast world of oracle. What I am trying to do is, creating a stored procedure and retrieve its result.
My procedure goes as

```
Create or Replace Procedure usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select(
afdelingId in varchar2,
productTypeId in varchar2,
productieData out sys_refcursor)
IS 
Begin
Open productieData for
Select Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer, Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer,
    Product.Omschrijving, Productieresultaatrtplrol.Bruto_In_Meters
    From Rotaplateproductie inner join Productieresultaatrtplrol on
    Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer = Productieresultaatrtplrol.Batchnummer 
    inner join Cpiplusproductieorder on 
    Productieresultaatrtplrol.ProductieNummer =  Cpiplusproductieorder.ProductNummer 
    inner join Product on
    Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer = Product.Productnummer
    Where Rotaplateproductie.Afdelingid = '3144' and Rotaplateproductie.producttype = 'PT005'   
END;
```

And using the below code I am trying to execute it.

```
var rc REFCURSOR
EXEC usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select('3144','PT005', :rc);
```

While executing the above lines I am getting Ora:00900 error.

When I run the query part of the procedure, it is running fine but with procedure it gives me error.

Comment: I ASSUME this procedure is valid right ?

Comment: The query is valid, but not sure about the procedure

Comment: Maverick next time dont accept unless you are sure if it does happen please ... please let us know why so any one can get use from this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shareef pointed out you're missing a semicolon on the statement inside your procedure, but it doesn't look like you're actually creating it properly. You need a `/` after the procedure to tell Oracle to execute the code and actually do the creation. I think it's seeing the `var` and `exec` statements as part of a single call, which is incorrect. But I'm also not sure how you're running this; if it's in SQL Developer you need to 'run script' (F5) rather than just 'run'.

```
Create or Replace Procedure usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select(
    p_afdelingId in varchar2,
    p_productTypeId in varchar2,
    p_productieData out sys_refcursor)
IS 
Begin
    Open p_productieData for
        Select Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer, Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer,
            Product.Omschrijving, Productieresultaatrtplrol.Bruto_In_Meters
        From Rotaplateproductie
        inner join Productieresultaatrtplrol on
            Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer = Productieresultaatrtplrol.Batchnummer 
        inner join Cpiplusproductieorder on 
            Productieresultaatrtplrol.ProductieNummer = Cpiplusproductieorder.ProductNummer 
        inner join Product on
            Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer = Product.Productnummer
        Where Rotaplateproductie.Afdelingid = p_afdelingId
        and Rotaplateproductie.producttype = p_productTypeId; 
END;
/
var rc REFCURSOR
EXEC usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select('3144','PT005', :rc);
print :rc
```

I've switched to use the IN parameters, and I've taken the liberty of changing the names so you can distinguish between parameters and column names; they were the same which can cause confusion.

You might also find it useful to alias your tables; no functional difference but maybe easier to read:

```
Create or Replace Procedure usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select(
    p_afdelingId in varchar2,
    p_productTypeId in varchar2,
    p_productieData out sys_refcursor)
IS 
Begin
    Open p_productieData for
        Select rp.Batchnummer, cppo.Productnummer,
            p.Omschrijving, pra.Bruto_In_Meters
        From Rotaplateproductie rp
        inner join Productieresultaatrtplrol par
            on rp.Batchnummer = pra.Batchnummer 
        inner join Cpiplusproductieorder cppo
            on pra.ProductieNummer = cppo.ProductNummer 
        inner join Product p
            on cppo.Productnummer = p.Productnummer
        Where rp.Afdelingid = p_afdelingId
        and rp.producttype = p_productTypeId; 
END;
/
```

If you get a message that the procedure compiled with warnings, do 'show errors' to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

did you run the code

```
Select Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer, Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer,
    Product.Omschrijving, Productieresultaatrtplrol.Bruto_In_Meters
    From Rotaplateproductie inner join Productieresultaatrtplrol on
    Rotaplateproductie.Batchnummer = Productieresultaatrtplrol.Batchnummer 
    inner join Cpiplusproductieorder on 
    Productieresultaatrtplrol.ProductieNummer =  Cpiplusproductieorder.ProductNummer 
    inner join Product on
    Cpiplusproductieorder.Productnummer = Product.Productnummer
    Where Rotaplateproductie.Afdelingid = '3144' and Rotaplateproductie.producttype = 'PT005'
```

i it works please reply 
i think you miss semicolon in the end

> **;**
>
> @Mavrik edited
>
> After adding semicolon in the end of the query, the procedure is
>   created properly. thanks but it is still returning the same error code
>   when I tried to execute it using the below code
>
> var rc REFCURSOR EXEC usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select('3144','PT005',
>   :rc);

**UPDATE 1:**
if you have ora 00900 it may be because of

[Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-00900 Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00900.php)

Comment: If it's all being run together, it's also possibly missing the `/` between the end of the procedure and the `var`. (And presumably the query should be using the `IN` parameters, not hard-coded values).

Comment: I will use them using IN parameters in future. just for testing I have done this way

Comment: @Maverick are you using sql plus

Comment: @shareef - Hi Shareef, semicolon helped to build the procedure successfully.  Thanks

Comment: @Maverick next time dont accept unless you are sure if it does happen please ... please let us know why so any one can get use from this question